# Where to download Mozilla addon cfx (and not jpm)?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

The page for cfx tells me it's no longer supported, but it's exactly what I need to work on an old add-on. Can someone show me where I can download it?

I say not jpm, because I've tried many times to transition the add-on to jpm, and they all failed, even though I followed the instructions in the cfx to jpm guide. I just need to change and test the add-on, and I can't do it with jpm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Addon-SDK lives on [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk).

The interesting thing about that, is that every revision is available to download. The old [Wiki page about cfx](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/wiki/cfx-py) references revision c37bf47de25551832b96a53d9cd15efe8bfa7c11, which can be easily accessed [here](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/c37bf47de25551832b96a53d9cd15efe8bfa7c11).

The file you're looking for seems to live under the *bin* directory.